# Connection error returned from successful microservices call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices

Consider a scenario where I have 3 microservices say A, B, and C.

Call pattern -> A is calling B and B is calling C.

It's a success scenario and all my APIs are returning the 200 success response but while returning the response to the client(UI) there is some connection error that occurs. So how the end-user will know whether his transaction is successful or not? How can we handle such scenarios in microservices? Please share your views.

Comment: try... catch statement?

Comment: No i dont think so

Comment: What do you mean is that the A call succeeds and the error occurs at the gateway or somewhere else?

Comment: A , B, and C C all 3 calls are successful (200 responses) but while the server is returning the 200 responses back to the client at that time connection error occurred. We have checked the logs of the production environment and found that all 3 calls have persisted the data in DB only when it was returning the success response to the UI at that time some connection error happened and the user didn't receive the success message on the screen. So, even though it was a successful case but user thought something is failed.

Comment: If it is a Client error (connection error) you cannot do nothing.

Comment: So, How the end-user will know whether his transaction is successful or not? Consider the same scenario in a banking application, User is sending some money from his account, and the amount is debited from his account but still, he got a failure message. How to deal with such scenarios?

Comment: You can have a functionality to preview pending transactions or API calls, during course of API calls, you can periodically publish events to messaging queues such as MQ, Kafka etc. with statuses (or a dead letter queue in case of errors or failed retries) and on the pending transactions page you can display event status. You can use DB also for such scenarios